# uninitialized constant UsersController with devise and rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, devise

I have configured a new rails 3 app, with devise and rspec. I have followed the devise wiki, and put

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
end
```

in spec/spec_helper.rb. Anyways, when I try to run the controllers spec, I have the error :

```
spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant UsersController (NameError)
```

Sounds like devise engine classes are not available in loadpath while testing. Any idea ?

Comment: Answer to myself, add a file app/controllers/users_controller.rb : class UsersController < ApplicationController ; end

Answer (score 0):

`UserController` might be missing.

If not, can you paste it here?